# Zoneminder image problem

Tags: raspbian, webcam, zoneminder

this is my first Raspberry Pi project, I'm making home surveillance system with Raspberry Pi and Zoneminder. I got it all up and running expect one and the most important thing, image, I can see the frame rate and it's between 5-7fps, but I can't see any image (no broken image symbol, just background). I'm using Wanscam IP camera, this model doesn't stream video, it sends large number of images in JPEG format. I read on Zoneminder web page that Wanscam is supported. I thought that maybe Raspberry Pi CPU can't handle streaming video so I programmed my own script and run it and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

zoneminder 'really' wants you to exactly match the height+width of your camera's output to the same setting in your config file - make sure they're exactly the same.